# The name of the PUBLIC class in the current CLASS POOL must be "..." not "..."

Tags: abap

I'm trying to create a local class (`Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS`) inside a global class (`Z_MY_GLOBAL_CLASS`) by clicking "Local Definitions/Implementations" in transaction `se24`.

[image: Button "Local Definitions/Implementations"]

Afterwards I copied the source code of another class from its source code-based view into the text area that showed up after I clicked the "local definitions" button.

[image]

```
*"* use this source file for the definition and implementation of
*"* local helper classes, interface definitions and type
*"* declarations

class Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS definition
  public
  final
  create public .

public section.

  class-methods SOME_STATIC_METHOD
    importing
      !IS_IS type Z_SOME_TYPE
    returning
      value(RS_RETURN) type Z_SOME_TYPE .
protected section.
private section.
ENDCLASS.



CLASS Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS IMPLEMENTATION.


* <SIGNATURE>---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | Static Public Method Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS=>SOME_STATIC_METHOD
* +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
* | [--->] IS_IN                   TYPE        Z_SOME_TYPE
* | [<-()] RS_RETURN               TYPE        Z_SOME_TYPE
* +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</SIGNATURE>
  method SOME_STATIC_METHOD.
    "" some coding
  endmethod.
ENDCLASS.
```

When trying to activate the coding I get the following message:

> The name of the PUBLIC class in the current CLASS POOL must be "Z_MY_GLOBAL_CLASS", not "Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS".

or in German:

> Der Name der PUBLIC-Klasse im aktuellen CLASS-POOL muß "Z_MY_GLOBAL_CLASS" statt "Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS" lauten.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As often within SAP/ABAP the error message does not describe the actual error. In the definition of your local class change these lines

```
class Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS definition
  public
  final
  create public .
```

to this

```
class Z_MY_LOCAL_CLASS definition final create public.
```

and it should compile. So the problem is that only global classes are allowed to contain [`public`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/abapclass_options.htm#!ABAP_ADDITION_1@1@). When copying/migrating source code from existing global classes to local classes you have to remove those lines.

Comment: Nearly correct. It's actually the `public` qualifier that's disturbing the compiler, as it declares the class to be visible through the data dictionary. The `create public` amendment only declares the class to be instantiable with `new` and is well accepted in private classes.