# The addition "PUBLIC" of the CLASS statement is missing in the global object type

Tags: abap

I'm trying to convert a local ABAP class to a "normal"/global class using the source code based view in transaction `se24`. The source code is:

```
CLASS Z_MY_CLASS definition.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS Z_MY_CLASS IMPLEMENTATION.
ENDCLASS.
```

When trying to activate there is an error message:

> The addition "PUBLIC" of the CLASS statement is missing in the global object type "Z_MY_CLASS".
>
> Bei dem globalen Objekttyp Z_MY_CLASS fehlt der Zusatz "PUBLIC" zur CLASS-Anweisung.

What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is exactly what says the message: "PUBLIC" is missing in "CLASS". You should better explain why this message was not obvious to you.

Comment: I was copying source code from a local class to a non-local class and wasn't aware of the additional keywords. I asked (and answered) this question so that googling the error message quickly leads to a minimal working and non-working example. Although it may seem obvious it's still useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the inverse problem of ["The name of the PUBLIC class in the current CLASS POOL must be “…” not"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58056207/10009545).

Here's a working version of the code:

```
CLASS Z_MY_CLASS definition.
  public
  "" inheriting from ... " optional
  "" final " optional
  create public.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  PROTECTED SECTION.
  PRIVATE SECTION.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS Z_MY_CLASS IMPLEMENTATION.
ENDCLASS.
```

The words `public final create public` resolve the error.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: `PUBLIC` will tell ABAP to publish this class as a globally available development object, esp. also through the Data Dictionary. The other amendments are optional. `FINAL` would prevent others from inheriting your class. `PUBLIC CREATE` will enable all consumers to instantiate the class with `DATA(instance) = NEW <class-name>( )`.